# $\mathbb{S}^2$ as a fibre bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

I know, by the Hopf fibration, that $\mathbb{S}^3$ is an $\mathbb{S}^1$-fibre bundle over $\mathbb{S}^2$.

Can $\mathbb{S}^2$ be an $\mathbb{S}^1$-fibre bundle over some manifold $M$?

Comment: related (more general question): [Which spheres are fiber bundles?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189535/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $F\to E\to B$ is a fiber bundle, $\chi(E)=\chi(F)\cdot\chi(B)$. But $\chi(S^1)=0$ and $\chi(S^2)=2\ne0$, so there is no $S^1$ bundle with total space $S^2$ (or with any even-dimensional sphere for that matter).

Comment: I actually prefer this answer to mine as it doesn't require $B$ to be a manifold, only that the Euler characteristic $\chi(B)$ exists. I'm not sure which concept is more approachable to a beginner though, the spectral sequence proof of the Euler characteristic identity of an orientable fibration, or the proof that there is an associated long exact sequence in homotopy to a Serre fibration.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you. In fact, identity $\chi(E)=\chi(F)\chi(B)$ doesn't require usage of spectral sequences: one can just cut $B$ in parts over which the fibration is trivial (e.g. cells) and use additivity of Euler char.

Comment: Ah, is that a simpler proof then in the case that we have a fiber bundle instead of a general fibration?

Comment: @Daniel Well, yes, as stated this argument works only for fiber bundles. But AFAICS it's not hard to extend it to all [Dold fibrations](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dold+fibration) (in particular, all Hurewicz fibrations): any such fibration is locally homotopy equivalent to direct product (and since $\chi$ is homotopy invariant, that's enough).

Answer (score 11):

The answer is no. Suppose $S^1\rightarrow S^2\rightarrow M$ is a fiber bundle sequence with $M$ a manifold. By the local product property, $M$ has dimension $1$ as a manifold and so is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $S^1$. However, by the long exact sequence in homotopy of this fiber bundle, we have a short exact sequence: $$0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\pi_2(M)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$$ and so $\pi_2(M)$ is non-trivial, hence $M$ can not be the real line or the circle.